# Kafka streams application does not consume messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have written a small kafka streams application that performs wordcount on input stream.My code looks like this

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

public class kafkastreams
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props=new Properties();
        props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"broker1,broker2");
        props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,"streams");

        props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"latest");
        props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

        KStreamBuilder builder=new KStreamBuilder();
        KStream<String,String> strings=builder.stream("input_topic");
        KTable<String,Long> wordcounts=
        strings.mapValues(value -> value.toLowerCase())
                .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split(",")))
                .selectKey((k,v)->v)
                .groupByKey()
                .count("counts");

       wordcounts.to(Serdes.String(),Serdes.Long(),"outputtopic");

       KafkaStreams streams=new KafkaStreams(builder,props);
       streams.start();
    }
}
```

My build.sbt file looks like this

```
name := "kstreams"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % "0.10.1.1"
```

I have packaged the application into a fat jar and have been trying to run it as

```
java -cp /path/to/the/fat/jar java-class-name
```

Once i submit the job,I see no response on the screen,other than
`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m`

I tried sending some test messages using the console producer,i see no response on the console nor there are any messages being sent to the output topic,which i am monitoring from a console consumer.

It would be great if anyone can help with this.

I am on a kerberized HDP cluster(2.6.3) and the kafka version is 0.10.1

Thanks.

Comment: How long did you run your application? I might just need more time to output anything as there is some internal caching. You can also disable caching by setting cache size to zero: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax. I would say i have given it more than 10 mins to push messages into another topic.I am assuming it is a security issue,Would appreciate any guidance on running Kafka Streams on Kerberos enabled cluster.

Comment: Late comment: If messages eventually arrive, and there is no other errors, then I don't think Kerberos is the issue

Answer (score 1):

check you have given bootstrap server correctly

```
props.setProperty(
    StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
    "broker1,broker2"
); -->default is localhost:9092
```

Make sure you have topics by the name `input_topic` and `outputtopic`

Expect to receive the message that has been sent to topic after your streaming is job has been started as you have included "latest" in the properties